# Integration IDP3 with existing local identity

Tags: .net, identityserver3

we have an existing application and we store the user information in some existing tables. The business need to expose some RESTful interface to public. We are thinking to use IdentityServer3 to perform authentication/authorization. However, it is not easy to get rid of the existing user tables and the security stuff. So we are thinking if there is any interface that we can implement so that the Identityserver3 can talk to the existing user table to perform authentication.

Any comment or example will be helpful for us.

Answer (score 3):

To integrate with your existing user store/tables you need to create a custom User Service within Identity Server. You do this by implementing `IUserService`.

Full docs on User Services [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html).